# Spring equivalent to @WebServiceRef?

Tags: spring, web-services, jax-ws

I'm having troubles using @WebServiceRef for unknown reasons... the injection is not happening. I would like to replace the use of @WebServiceRef with another annotation like @Resource. How could I make such a replacement ? I'm very new to jax-ws and spring configurations...